# jQuery and AJAX load html, select element within, and append to current DOM

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am developing a jQuery script that loads the html from the next page and appends it to the current container. Basically making a never-ending page. However the function is returning with an error, though `errorThrown` is blank. Is this the correct way to get html through ajax and append it to the current DOM?

```
$.ajax({type : "GET",
        url : currentUrl + "/page/" + nextPageNumber,
        dataType : "html",
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus); alert(errorThrown); },
        success : function(data) {
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
            frag.appencChild($(data)[0]);
            var $page = $(frag); 
            $("div.blueline-page-container").append($page.find('div.blueline-page-container').html());
            nextPageNumber++;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone that answered, it really helped point me in the right direction. For those who stumble upon this from a search, this is how I did it in the end:

```
$("div.blueline-page-container").append("<div id='blueline-page-" + nextPageNumber + "'><div>");
$("#blueline-page-" + nextPageNumber).load("/page/" + nextPageNumber + " div.blueline-page-container");
```

I add a `<div>` to the page with a unique id, then load the ajax results to the `<div>` created.

Simple in the end...

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use:

`$("selector").load(htmlhere);`

It works well with html.

Comment: Ok, I have read up on the documentation on that and it looks like thats exactly what I need. I implemented and still didn't work so I went fishing a little more. I am discovering that my `currentUrl` is returning with only `/` I am using `currentUrl = window.location.pathname;` to get the url. Any thoughts?

Comment: Found it. I need to use `hostname` not `pathname`

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "appencChild", for starters.  If you're trying to load an ID, you can already specify a fragment by using whatever.html#yourId in $.load()'s URL string.  If you have more specific needs, you can simply pass the response HTML to jQuery and operate on it as a normal jQuery object:

```
...
success : function(data) {
    var $page = $(data);
    $("div.blueline-page-container").append($page.find('div.blueline-page-container').html());
}
...
```